# Quarkus app runs perfectly on local but does not respond to any request on windows server

Tags: api, quarkus, windows-server-2008, quarkus-rest-client

I have a simple quarkus api app. I've tested the app on my local machine and its running fine. But when i try to run the same app in windows server it starts perfect but does not respond to any of my api request. It is not showing any error or problems. I've tried multiple ways to run the app also through package and jar files but all led to same result. [screenshot of the palce where app gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0XMn.png)

Comment: The screenshot shows a perfectly normal startup of a Quarkus application in dev mode.

Comment: Exactly! It starts perfectly but whenever i try to hit the api in Postman it does not respond. The app does not get triggered by any input. And this happens only in windows server but the same project runs perfectly on my local machine

Comment: I take it you don't want the app to start in dev mode, and yet it starts in dev mode? Or it starts in dev mode as intended, but then doesn't work?

Comment: it starts in dev mode but doesnt work.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you file an issue in the Quarkus issue tracker: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues And please at least attach a stack trace (using `jstack`), because the screenshot here can't really be used to diagnose anything.

Comment: Actually i found the solution. I need to add hostname in application.properties file. quarkus.http.host= *hostname*

Comment: @NabilAnsari facing a similar issue when running the Quarkus app in dev mode on Windows machine. Could you explain more about what you did and any thoughts on how it got fixed?

Answer (score 0):

check your application properties configurations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).